# How to disable Windows lockscreen shortcut

Tags: c#, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to disable Windows lock screen shortcut, because I want to remap it to some other function, but I don't want to disable actual computer locking mechanism.

I know that I can disable lockscreen altogether, this is not what I'm after.

I used this example: https://github.com/kverpoorten/BabyKeyboardBash

I changed the global keyboard hook to ignore all events if it detects that Left Win key is down. If LWin is down, I send a dummy key event.
All the LWin + KEY shortcuts are ignored, except Windows lockscreen shortcut. It seems that Windows catches that event before my app does.

Here is what is changed: https://github.com/kverpoorten/BabyKeyboardBash/blob/master/Keyboard.cs (line 198)

```
 private IntPtr HookCallback( int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam)
 {
     if ((NativeMethods.GetKeyState(VK_LWIN) & 0x8000) != 0)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("LWin down!");
          return (System.IntPtr)1;
      }
 }
```

Currently I'm only testing if I can even catch the lockscreen shortcut. Everything so for suggests it is not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: There are certain key sequences (such as CTRL-ALT-DELETE) that windows gets first, and the whole point is that you can *trust* that Windows is the system responding, not someone else's malicious program attempting to trick the user into revealing their password.

Comment: Which is all good and understandable, and CTRL-ALT-DEL is universally one of those. I'm thinking that lock screen should not be one of those. If you have a service on your pc that can hijack your Win+L keys, you're screwed already. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was under the impression that keylogger will catch your keys even on the lock screen.

Comment: You're wrong.  The intention of the secure desktop (aka lock screen) is to defeat keyloggers.